# The Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: asp.net

I had developed a web application using Visual Studio 2010 which one of the function is to import Excel file(.xls).However when I deployed the web application over the Server(Windows Server 2003) the following error will occurred:

> "The Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine".

This problem doesn't exist when I deployed it in Windows 7.

Please advice me regarding how to solve this problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As your web application cannot work in 32 bit mode, you may switch to this driver,

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

As it has pure 64 bit version. Read through the whole page so as to understand what you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 64 bit version of Server 2003, MS Jet Engine doesn't have 64 bit port. Running on a 64-bit machine will default to a 64-bit web application pool and it will not be able to find the 32-bit version of the Jet engine component.

The solution for 64 bit machine is to configure the application pool and enable 32-bit application support on IIS 6(Server 2003) as below link.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435

Comment: With respect to your link,i have tried the ASP.NET 2.0, 32-bit version.However i get a "Service Unavailable" error.

Comment: @weizz Is app pool or website stopped?

Comment: Service Unavailable is expected if your web application does rely on pure 64 bit dlls.

Comment: then is there any way to change the dlls to 32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

you need t install Office System Data driver. go and download the tools and install it. it will register the Jet Engine to Local pc

[Office 2007 System Data Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734)